# Почему я не могу получит file_id?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вот результат, при выводе через print:

[<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x0000026AD9EF5F48>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x0000026AD9F13AC8>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x0000026AD9F13708>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x0000026AD9F13A08>]

А вот необходимый результат, который выводится в Телеграм, а скрипт видит тот, что находится выше (то бишь не этот):

{'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkDAAIVtmDkeRZW6BDKvGfHCDdKlm6n-R89AAJ9tjEbnxYoS1OmsWjpYKoPAQADAgADcwADIAQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADfbYxG58WKEt4', 'width': 62, 'height': 90, 'file_size': 1551}

```
def find_file_ids(message):
for file in os.listdir('photo/'):
    if file.split('.')[-1] == 'jpg':
        f = open('photo/'+file, 'rb')
        res = bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, f, None)
        print(res)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Мне же нужно получить тот результат, который выводится в самом Телеграм, а затем получить file_id фотографии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_id` находится в объекте `PhotoSize`. Просто берите последний элемент из массива и получайте id файла:

```py
def find_file_ids(message):
for file in os.listdir('photo/'):
    if file.split('.')[-1] == 'jpg':
        f = open('photo/'+file, 'rb')
        res = bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, f, None)
        file_id = res[-1].file_id
        print(res)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я с эти пол дня мучался